# Second Countability hypothesis for a Banach manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, banach-manifold, partition-of-unity

Is the second countability hypothesis necessary to rigoruosly define a Banach Manifold (say in infinite dimension)?

In the finite-dimensional theory of manifolds, that request is included in the formal definiton in order to guarantee the existence of the partitions of unity.

In Banach Manifolds (infinite dimension), is there some other method to have the existence of differentiable partitions of unity?

Thanks

Comment: What's the definition of "partition of unity" on a Banach manifold?  In finite dimensions, one of the requirements is that the functions in question are compactly supported, which obviously won't work in the infinite-dimensional case.

Comment: See Chapter 2, Section 3 of Lang's _Fundamentals of Differential Geometry_. (His book develops as much of the theory as he can without the finite dimension assumptions, and only adds in those when he needs it. In particular, he definition of a manifold, finite or infinite dimensional, does not require second countability.

Comment: In the Hilbert case, paracompact manifolds modeled on a separable Hilbert space has differentiable partitions of unity (ibid). In the same section Lang also points to [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183526658) which shows that even just a plain-old Banach space may fail to have a (differentiable) partition of unity.  // @NateEldredge: Lang defines partition of unity by requiring the cut-off functions be such that they sum to 1 everywhere, are non-negative, and the set of their supports form a locally finite covering.

Comment: Of course one doesn't need $A_2$ to define a Banach manifold -any Banach space is a Banach manifold after all; and, as a metric space, it is certainly paracompact. The problem with partitions of unity is more about regularity: a Banach space may fail to have a non-zero $C^1$ function  with bounded support. So in general one can't do better than a locally Lipschitz partition of unity (yet quite a lucky circumstance: one can then build at ease locally Lipschitz fields, which is what is needed in ODE for local existence, uniqueness and continuous dependence!)